# Getting a NULL return from a 0 row dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function that sometimes returns a value of NULL and sometimes returns a data frame with 0 rows.  I would like do something else.  Say that object `x` is an object that can be `NULL` or 0 rows

```
x1 <- some operation on x
if(is.null(x) & is.null(x1) { do stuff }
```

I'm trying to think of a way to query a data frame that will return `NULL` if it has 0 rows and will return something that is not `NULL` if it has any rows.  That is because the following does not work:

```
while(is.null(x) | dim(x)[1] == 0) { do stuff }
```

because when x is null you get a argument is of length zero error when you query `dim(x)`

Every thing I can think of returns `<NA>` and not `NULL`.  Actually I think my code would look like

```
while(is.null(x) & is.null(some.operation(x)) { do stuff }
```

Comment: Why are you using `|` instead of `||`? Does `while(is.null(x) || dim(x)[1]==0){do stuff}` work for you?

Comment: I'm such a noob.  Yes, I haven't gotten around to testing yet, but I'm pretty sure that || will work.  I think that this article would still be good to have out there, because if you don't know about || or have forgotten about it, there isn't much out there to direct you to it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then you just need to change

```
while(is.null(x)|dim(x)[1]==0){do stuff}
```

to

```
while(is.null(x) || dim(x)[1]==0){do stuff}
```

The logical OR (`|`) operator is vectorised. This both sides are always evaluated, e.g. we always evaluate `is.null(x)` and `dim(x)`.

In contrast, the operator `||` works for scalers (actually it also works on vectors, but only uses the first value). This means that we only evaluate `dim(x)` **if** `is.null(x)` returns `FALSE`.

For example

```
# Vectorised, so stop is called
TRUE | stop("Now!")
#Error: Now!
```

with

```
# Scaler: stop is not evaluated.
TRUE || stop("Now!")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Mind adding the reason of why the RHS is not evaluated with || ? because TRUE or whatever will always be true, that's not always easy to understand at first glance ;)

Comment: Don't think vectorization plays any role here. I'd quote what the doc says at `?"|"`: `The longer form
     evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
     vector.  Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.
     The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and
     typically preferred in ‘if’ clauses.`

Comment: @nicola To also quote: `The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators` - this is vectorization

Comment: To give link at my previous comment: [Short-circuit_evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

This function will return NULL if the data.frame has 0 rows or the number of rows if the data.frame is has at least one row.

```
myFunc <- function(x) return(list(NULL, nrow(x))[[(!(is.null(nrow(x) > 0))) + 1L]])
```

I use `list` to encapsulate NULL as an element that can be returned. The second element of the list is the number of rows Then, the proper list element is returned with `[[`.

Here are a couple of test examples

```
# NULL input
myFunc(NULL)
NULL
# empty data.frame
myFunc(data.frame())
NULL
# data.frame with single element
myFunc(data.frame(a=1))
# data.frame with vector of length 10
[1] 1
myFunc(data.frame(a=1:10))
[1] 10
```

Comment: It's still overkill over a simple OR as shown in other answer (it does create count the rows, create a list, then cout the rows again, test if they are > 0, test if this is not null and then select in the list after an addition), but it works now.

Comment: I would not disagree with that assessment.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution of:

```
makeNull<-function(x){
  if(is.null(x)) {return(x)}
  if(dim(x)[1]==0) {x<-NULL}
  x
}
```

so then I would enter

```
while(is.null(x)&is.null(makeNull(x)){do stuff}
```

to replace

```
while(is.null(x)|dim(x)[1]){do stuff}
```

Comment: You should not need is.null(x) (as your function already take care of it). And really try to understand the difference between `&` and `&&` (and also  between `|` and `||`) as your actual code add more overhead than what is shown by csgillespie above. Side note, think about marking accepted (grey tick left of the answer which will turn green) the answer you feel is the most useful for you.